# Use every for functions as object property

Tags: javascript

I have validate map for article.

```
var articleMap = {
    author: function (author) {
        if(author) {
            return author.length > 0;
        }
    },
    title: function (title) {
        if (!title) {
            return title.length > 0;
        }
    }
};
```

And this is example of article to validate

```
var article =
        {
            id: '1',
            title: '«Title',
            summary: 'Summary',
            createdAt: new Date(2017, 3, 5, 8, 0),
            author: 'John',
            content: 'Content',
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
            picture: 'images/id_1.jpeg'
        };
```

And when i use every for `Object.keys` it uses only first key. But when i use `forEach` everything is okay. Also my code must work correctly when i don't have some keys in article(for example `'content'`). What should i fix?

```
 Object.keys(articleMap).every(function (item) {
        alert(articleMap[item](article[item]));
    });
```

Comment: This is because you return nothing (`undefined`) from the callback which is falsy.

Comment: @georg https://jsfiddle.net/q4stx5mn/ so this is correct?

Comment: `if (!title) return title.length > 0;` makes no sense

Comment: @Vladislav Yes, that fiddle looks fine

Comment: "*must work when i don't have some keys in article*" - what do you expect to happen then? Should the properties that don't exist both in the object and the validation map just be ignored? (i.e. an empty object is always valid)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forEach` and not `every`:

```
Object.keys(articleMap).forEach(function (item) {
        alert(articleMap[item](article[item]));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information:

The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) { 

  return element >= 10; 
} 

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);   // false 
[12, 54, 18, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough); // true
```

while in the other hand:

The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

a.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Always good to check the documentation first!